# Ubuntu 14.04 on Apple Macbook Air late 2010, 3-2 - installation not possible

Tags: usb, system-installation, mac, macbook, macosx

Starting from a live usb stick, according to: [create a usb stick on mac osx](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)
is not possible.
I downloaded ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

The same behaviour appears with rEFIt installed.

Can anybody help me? I'd love to get ubuntu running.

Comment: I have late 2010 Mac Air. I think the best way is to create the USB disk on an ubuntu machine. I tried to create both images on osx but neither boots. Finally I created the USB disk using x86 Ubuntu. It boots OK and I chose to try not install. The whole system froze after several minutes, while I was using firefox to search online about why the display scrambles sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: [the guide for 13.04 also applies for 14.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir3-2/Raring)**

**Longer answer:** Apple does not let you boot any non Mac operating system from USB on the 2010 version of the Air. The easiest (and safest) way is booting from a [SuperDrive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperDrive). I tried booting the Ubuntu installation disk from an additional partition on my harddisk [similar to this description](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10886829&postcount=320), but probably corrupted my boot partition in the progress. [This turned out to be worse than expected, because it's not easy to boot a 2010 MacBook Air from any other medium than the harddisk in a scenario like this.](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/70171/%5BSOLVED%5D+Startup+chime,+no+boot,+white+screen+of+death) That said, I'm sure I made a mistake and it should be possible to install Ubuntu that way. If you try, just be sure to know what you're doing. **If you have access to an Apple SuperDrive, make your life a lot easier by using this option!**

I finally installed Ubuntu without any problems from a DVD via a SuperDrive (I did not use the "try"-option, just installed it to a separate partition created in Mac OS Disk Manager before).

@user275168: [Check the Ubuntu installation guide for 13.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir3-2/Raring) for information on how to [fix the graphics driver on the MacBook Air 2010](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir3-2/Raring#Install_NVIDIA_drivers). You need to get the proprietary version of the driver from Nvidia. I installed it and everything works like a charm ever since.